# Add UIView as SuperView subView from its own UView SubClass

Tags: ios, uiview, subclass, addsubview, superview

Actually I think this one is very simple, and I'm missing something.

I'm creating Subclass of UIView, and instead of adding it as a subView from the ViewController like this :

```
rateus = RateFrameWork(AppID: "asdasds", BackGroundColor: UIColor.blueColor())
self.addSubView(rateus)
```

I'm trying adding it from the subclass, this is what I tried so far :

```
class RateFrameWork: UIView
```

1) From the super init coder(dosent work)

```
 required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        superview?.addSubview(self)

    }
```

2) From the init method(dosent work)

```
init?(AppID: String!, BackGroundColor: UIColor!)
super.init(frame: CGRect(x:  0 , y: 0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width , height:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height))
 superview?.addSubview(self)
```

Any suggestions? **How can I add it as subview from its own subclass?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it because this is contradictory to the idea.

A view does not have superview unless it's to be added as subview, and a view does not know that it would be added as a subview under what circumstances and when.

Some special views(e.g. AlertView、ActionView) can be added to the `keyWindow` but your view not.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your answer! I been td that i can do something like InitWithSuperVIew, are you familiar with this?

Comment: Eh… I prefer to use `showInView` rather than `initWithSuperView` that like `UIActionSheet`

Comment: Actually I have no idea whats the differences. One of these method add it to superView via the init process?

Comment: I think the differences is that `showInView` called by its superview. A side of advantage is that it will be initialized but not visible. Its superview can decides when to show.

Comment: I used this command from the subclass or when i declare the object(in the view did load for example)